# wget Unable to establish SSL connection on bash script install

Tags: bash, openssl, wget

I'm trying to install a github file through bash following these instructions

https://github.com/allenai/s2orc-doc2json

```
bash scripts/setup_grobid.sh
```

but I'm getting the following error

```
bash scripts/setup_grobid.sh
SYSTEM_WGETRC = c:/progra~1/wget/etc/wgetrc
syswgetrc = c:/progra~1/wget/etc/wgetrc
--2022-07-21 20:55:25--  https://github.com/kermitt2/grobid/archive/0.6.1.zip
Resolving github.com... 140.82.121.4
Connecting to github.com|140.82.121.4|:443... connected.
OpenSSL: error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version
Unable to establish SSL connection.
unzip:  cannot find or open 0.6.1.zip, 0.6.1.zip.zip or 0.6.1.zip.ZIP.
rm: cannot remove '0.6.1.zip': No such file or directory
scripts/setup_grobid.sh: line 11: cd: /c/Users/User/grobid-0.6.1: No such file or directory
scripts/setup_grobid.sh: line 12: ./gradlew: No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat '/c/Users/User/git/s2orc-pdf2json/pdf2json/grobid/config.yaml': No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat '/c/Users/User/git/s2orc-pdf2json/pdf2json/grobid/grobid.properties': No such file or directory
scripts/setup_grobid.sh: line 22: ./gradlew: No such file or directory
```

This is the setup_grobid.sh after running it through `ShellCheck.net`

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# put in your pdf2json directory here
export PDF2JSON_HOME=$HOME/Desktop/s2orc-doc2json-main

# Download Grobid
cd "$HOME" || exit
wget https://github.com/kermitt2/grobid/archive/0.6.1.zip
unzip 0.6.1.zip
rm 0.6.1.zip
cd "$HOME"/Desktop/s2orc-doc2json-main/grobid-0.6.1 || exit
./gradlew clean install

## Grobid configurations
# increase max.connections to slightly more than number of processes
# decrease logging level
# this isn't necessary but is nice to have if you are processing lots of files
cp "$PDF2JSON_HOME"/pdf2json/grobid/config.yaml "$HOME"/grobid-0.6.1/grobid-service/config/config.yaml
cp "$PDF2JSON_HOME"/pdf2json/grobid/grobid.properties "$HOME"/grobid-0.6.1/grobid-home/config/grobid.properties

## Start Grobid
./gradlew run
```

I even tried to `--no-check-certificate` but still got the same error.

edit: I'm using Wget 1.11.4 / OpenSSL 1.1.1q  5 Jul 2022

Comment: As the `bash` tag you added instructs, `For shell scripts with syntax or other errors, please check them at https://shellcheck.net before posting here.` then re-run it and let us know if you still have a problem.

Comment: Would you mind posting what versions of wget and openssl are you using?

Comment: @N1ngu Wget 1.11.4 / OpenSSL 1.1.1q  5 Jul 2022

Comment: @EdMorton thank you for the tip, I applied all the suggested fixes from shellcheck but I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: You're welcome, please [edit] your question to replace the old script with your new corrected one so we can see the script you're now running so we can help you with that.

Comment: You have this tagged [tag:windows-subsystem-for-linux], but it seems to me that you are using Git Bash, right?  If so, please delete the incorrect tag - Thanks!

Comment: Also, it doesn't appear to me that this is *programming related*.  Problems running someone else's code are "usage" (general-computing) issues, rather than programming issues.  Nor is the code you are attempting to run a "programming tool" -- It's document conversion, right?  You might want to consider either [Super User](https://superuser.com) or [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com) as a better place for this type of question.  Thanks!

Comment: Finally, you have this tagged [tag:python], but there's no Python code in question here either, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Telling by

```
OpenSSL: error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version
```

this might be caused by github droping support for ancient TLS version protocols https://github.blog/2018-02-01-crypto-removal-notice/ and a fairly outdated wget+openssl installation.

Try forcing a specific modern TLS protocol and see how it goes

```
wget --secure-protocol=TLSv1_2 https://github.com/kermitt2/grobid/archive/0.6.1.zip
```

or try to upgrade your installation

---

As a rule of thumb, start your scripts with

```
set -ex
```

So that they

1. stop if any instruction fails
2. echo the instruction that is being executed

Comment: This gave me a new error `C:\Windows\system32\wget: --secure-protocol: Invalid value `TLSv1_2'.`

Comment: This confirms my suspicion. There is no way you are gonna make that version of wget talk to a modern website. I think wget 1.11.4 is more than 10 years old. You can only upgrade it or replace the software used for download.

Comment: I replaced `wget` with `aria2c` and it looks like it's downloading but it's very slow. Hopefully that will solve the problem.